# GitHub oauth process with changing scopes

Tags: oauth-2.0, github-api

I'm using GitHub's oauth for registration and authentication on a site.

The flow is like this:

- A User clicks on `sign up with github` and is then redirected to the oauth login page on GitHub where I ask for the scope `user:email`.
- Once the user has successfully logged in on GitHub, I receive the callback, create a user and log the user in to my site.

That's working great, but I run into problems when changing the scopes later on.

Imagine the following:

A user signs up like in my example above and wants to use a feature later on where my app needs access to private repositories. I'll send the user through the oauth process again to add the `repo` scope and save the new token.

The user now logs out or uses a different device. When he wants to log back in, I have to send him through the oauth process again but **I have no information about the scopes that were added later on**.

When the user granted my application the `repo` scope and the oauth process just asks for the `user:email` scope (or no scope at all) the scopes that were added later on (in my example the `repo` scope) get dropped.

Is there a way to kick off a plain login process where I don't have to add any scopes and GitHub just confirms that the user that wants to log in is the user I have on record?

Is this the way oauth is supposed to work, or am I missing something important here?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is not for signing in users to your website; it is for transportation of tokens that allow users of your website (that you've authenticated yourself or through some other means) to interact with their Github repo's/accounts; see also: http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/

Comment: That's true for an arbitrary oauth provider. If you take e.g. GitHub, you can request the username (which is unique) with the obtained token and authenticate a user with this information.

Comment: you can't authenticate the user with that: the thing that it tells you is who granted the token to your client but it does not mean that that user is actually authenticated at this point in time; that's exactly what the article is about